# Y-coordinates offset in Tilemill

Tags: postgis, tilemill, mbtiles

I own a project created with TileMill in SRS 900913. The data source is a Postgis database with the same SRS.

When I'm loading the file generated with TileMill (mbtiles) in QGIS and I'm putting under an orthophoto with the same SRS, or the original Postgis layer, the mapping displayed is moved approximately 2.5 meters moves in the Y axis relative to the PostGIS layer.

However if I'm loading QGIS directly from a PostGIS data source, works like a charm (think). Is like TileMill is displacing it because, as I said, loading the postgis layer directly from the database is working fine. In this image, you could see the Y offset between postgis (marked in blue), and mbtiles raster (marked in black)

[image: postgis layer and mbtiles layer]

Anyone know what could be happening?

Comment: 2.5 metres displacement at what latitude?

Comment: Postgis layer (the correct layer) has this coordinates: -659215.06,5397190.63, and the mbtiles layer, for the same element has -659214.77,5397188.39

Answer (score 1):

Solved. It is a QGIS bug with mbtiles format. I have QGIS 2.6.1-Brighton. It shifted the mbtiles 3m south. If I load the mbtiles file in my leaflet project, it fits perfectly.

Comment: Confirmed here with own mbtiles, even with datasources in WGS84. It is not a QGIS bug; if I use GDAL to transform to geotiff, it is shifted too.

Answer (score 0):

SRS 900913 is not supported by QGIS anymore. It has been officially replaced by EPSG:3857, but the mapnik people still stick to their 900913. The projection has some pitfalls which are only solved if QGIS recognizes it correctly. If you load data from a OSM postgis database, a custom CRS will be created for it.

You don't write how you add the tilemill tiles. If you set the layer CRS to EPSG:3857, it should come out fine.

Comment: Actually the SRS layer in Tilemill is 900913, the Postgis source is EPSG:3857 (created with ogr2ogr from DGN source). But if in SRS field (Tilemill) I select Custom "+init=EPSG:3857" or the QGIS definition for EPSG:3857 - WGS84 / Pseudo Mercator "+proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0.0 +lon_0=0.0 +x_0=0.0 +y_0=0 +k=1.0 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +wktext  +no_defs" the result layer has the same problem. I'm confusing about that. The final result will be showed in a Leaflet map with EPSG:3857 projection.

Comment: I read this in a blog: "Also, projection code 900913 must be defined as the spatial reference when you are using files that you originally projected into EPSG:3857 using OGR. The two projections are equivalent, but if you leave TileMill to autodetect the spatial reference, you will see an offset from Google's tiles due to the way the projection parameters are interpreted."  It seems that I'm configuring the layer in the right way, but it's failing.

Comment: Can you link to that blogpost in your question? Maybe you should set your postgis database to 900913 as well.

Comment: [link]https://www.e-education.psu.edu/geog585/node/711. The issue is that the final project must be in EPSG:3857